# Is there any freeware for remote access via web browser?

Tags: windows-7, browser, webserver, remote-access, remote-control

I have a PC at home which I want to access from a web browser at school.

I looked for many software solutions but they had at least one of the following problems:

- Not free
- Need to install client software (I want to access my PC from a web browser)

The school’s computers have Java and SilverLight installed in the browers.

Is there a way to access my home system from the school’s browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this with [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) which comes with a Java based web client.

Comment: including like typing "http://my.pc.ip/" and then it will run that Java client or do I have to set up a separate web server?

Comment: @GamErix You need to use the specific port, but I think it should work out of the box, as long as the ultra vnc server itself is running

Comment: indeed VNC has a web server with java client auto run, my.external.ip:5556 works nice :)

Comment: UltraVNC uses 5800 as default HTTP port.

Answer (score 5):

You could try Teamviewer - the software has to be installed on your home PC but it is free for personal use and can be used via the browser.

Once installed on your home computer

- Head over to [Teamviewer's Web Login portal](https://beta.teamviewer.com/Account/LogOn)
- Login to your Teamviewer account
- Connect to your home computer from any browser (at school or else where).

Comment: I cannot install *anything* on the school PC, nor run .EXE's

Comment: I never said you needed to! Please re-read the answer.

Comment: teamviewer requires a installed client as long as I remember? (or at least a exe to be ran)

Comment: Fine, up to you if you don't want to believe me.

Comment: you could at least add a 2 or 3 step how-to for teamviewer ;)

Comment: I'm not here to hold your hand, plus, you don't think it works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is an extension for the Google Chrome web browser that will allow you to do this. It is called **Chrome Remote Desktop**. You can install the extension from the Chrome Webstore.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

It will allow you to remotely access another computer through Chrome browser or a Chromebook.  Computers can be made available on an short-term basis for scenarios such as ad hoc remote support, or on a more long-term basis for remote access to your applications and files.  All connections are fully secured.

Chrome Remote Desktop is fully cross-platform.  Provide remote assistance to Windows, Mac and Linux users, or access your Windows (XP and above) and Mac (OS X 10.6 and above) desktops at any time, all from the Chrome browser on virtually any device, including Chromebooks.

**Updated**: If your school does not use the Google Chrome web browser, the easiest way is to install a portable version of Google Chrome on a USB Stick at home
http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Then install the Chrome Remote Desktop Extension to the portable version

Comment: exes not allowed from usb :p

Comment: @GamErix - Ah OK...but if your school does have Chrome installed on the computers, I guess their is nothing stopping you from installing the extension it works v.well

Answer (score 1):

Try logmein.com, you can access your computer from a web interface if you have the software installed on your home PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [VNC Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vnc-viewer-for-google-chr/iabmpiboiopbgfabjmgeedhcmjenhbla?hl=en) from your Google Chrome browser. It's free to use.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answer but, free and without install/configuration client side (not even using Java or Silverlight, just plain javascript), you have browser based remote desktop solutions like [Guacamole](https://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-client) for Linux or [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you aren't able to execute anything or install anything then you might have better luck using Remote Desktop that's built-in to Windows.

I doubt your school removed access to RDP and if you can access a command prompt and type "mstsc" you should get the Remote Desktop Window. At home, you'll need to forward Port 3389 on your router to point to your PC.  Then it should allow you in.

Comment: they cought me with a command prompt and blocked it :P their internal server is easy to acces with RDP, after they discovered it was too late but finally they removed it too.

Comment: are you able to plug in a flash drive and run mstsc.exe yourself?

Comment: exe running is disabled, I could bypass it but I preffer not to "hack" the school.

Comment: I see...my last resort in a situation like this would be onlinevnc.com

Answer (score 0):

[Logmein.](https://secure.logmein.com/) You need to install software on your home computer, but not your school computer. You can then control your PC through a web browser. They have a paid version, but the free version works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DeskRoll](https://deskroll.com) - is web based remote access tool, with 30 day's trial

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.